# SqlRowSet returning null, but why?

Tags: java, spring

So this is where im trying to get the data from the database, but my sqlRowSet keeps returning null.

I defined it

```
private SqlRowSet sqlRowSet;



@Override
public Timeseddel read() {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM timeseddel";
    sqlRowSet = jdbc.queryForRowSet(sql);

    while (sqlRowSet.next()) {

        return new Timeseddel(sqlRowSet.getInt("timeseddel_id"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("appendix"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_fredag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_lordag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_mandah"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_onsdag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_sondag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_tirsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_torsdag"),
                sqlRowSet.getInt("fk_user_id"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("i_alt_timer"), sqlRowSet.getString("kunde"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_fredag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_lordag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_mandag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_onsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_sondag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_tirsdag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_torsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_fredag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_lordag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_mandag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_onsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_sondag"),
                sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_tirsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_torsdag"), sqlRowSet.getInt("uge_nr"));


    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your tables aren't empty.
2. You can't return from function multiple times. Collect the data into container and return container. Something like this:

   `ArrayList<Timeseddel> ret = new ArrayList<Timeseddel>();`

   ```
           while (sqlRowSet.next()) {

               ret.add( new Timeseddel(sqlRowSet.getInt("timeseddel_id"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("appendix"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_fredag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_lordag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_mandah"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_onsdag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_sondag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_tirsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("c_time_torsdag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getInt("fk_user_id"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("i_alt_timer"), sqlRowSet.getString("kunde"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_fredag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_lordag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_mandag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_onsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_sondag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_tirsdag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("o_time_torsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_fredag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_lordag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_mandag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_onsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_sondag"),
                       sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_tirsdag"), sqlRowSet.getDouble("p_time_torsdag"), sqlRowSet.getInt("uge_nr"));

           }

           return ret;
   ```